# Colliding with html element function returns false, even if theres an element in X, Y position

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a Chrome extension which puts an emoji shmeji into your site.
When i made a function that checks if X, Y position is colliding with element, 
It only returns false.
But it is actually colliding with some of HTML elements.
How can I fix it?
Here's my code:

```js
var emoji = document.createElement('span');
// ...
var hold = false;
var emojix = Math.round(window.innerWidth / 2);
var emojiy = Math.round(window.innerHeight / 2);
var emojively = 0;
var emojivelx = 0;
var emojis = ["","","","","☺","","","","", "", "", "", "", ""];
var skip = false
// ...
function htmlcol(x, y) {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('body *'); // Get all elements within the body

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var rect = elements[i].getBoundingClientRect(); // Get the boundaries of the element
    if (
      x >= rect.left &&
      x <= rect.right &&
      y >= rect.top &&
      y <= rect.bottom
    ) {
      return true
      break
    } else {
      return false}
  }
}
function update() {
  // ...
  if (chckycol(emojiy) || htmlcol(emojix, emojiy)) {
    emojively = 0;
  } else {
    if (!hold) {
      emojively += 0.07;
    } else {
      emojively = 0;
    }
  }
  // ...
}
// ...
updates = setInterval(update,10);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that the htmlcol was thinking that emoji was on emoji element (itself)
And also i putted `return false` into the end of loop.
And it worked like normal.

Answer (score 0):

htmlcol starts looping over every element descended from the body.

It tests the first element and then either returns true or false.

This exits the function, terminating the loop in the process.

It never checks the second element.

Only return when you want to exit the loop. (You probably want to move the return false to after the loop).

Comment: That didnt work when i placed `return false;` into end of loop

Comment: But it made the shmeji itself float.